# Why does Wicket change the action attribute of a non-Wicket form tag?

Tags: java, wicket

In the base template for the pages of my Wicket application, there's a form I don't want Wicket to handle, like this:

```
<form id="myForm" action="">
  <!-- input fields and submit button -->
</form>
```

I left the `action` attribute empty to always send it to the current page. On the application's main page, it works, but on other pages, Wicket adds a "../" in the action attribute, which seems to be meant well but is not what I want.

I'm using Wicket 1.4.17. How can I stop or change this behaviour?

The form is meant to enable the user to submit a short message as feedback to the site admin. It appears on every page and the input is collected from the `PageParameters` in the constructor of my pages' base class. If there is a more Wicket way to do this, I'll appreciate hints, but this should be a) stateless and b) very very simple.

Comment: Sounds to me as if Wicket automatically inserts the context path.  Have you tried adding an AttributeModifier instead of setting the action attribute of the HTML tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go the Wicket way and write a component for your feedback form which is then inserted into every page. As you have an (abstract) base class for all of your pages, you can simply add it there and it will appear on every page.

In your feedback form component, simply overwrite the onSubmit() method and send the message to the site admin.

Comment: Will that be stateless and always redirect to the originating page? I don't want the form component to cause serialization of all my pages to the session.

Comment: @HannoFietz AFAIK there exists a [StatelessForm](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/StatelessForm.html) exactly for this purpose. In the `onSubmit()` method you can call `setResponsePage(getPage().getClass())` to achieve the redirect. If you also have to respect page parameters, you have to pass them to the component. If you want to have more proof, you can also use the `wicket-devutils` library, especially the annotation `StatelessComponent` and the associated `StatelessChecker`.